# Confused log_trace function

Tags: c++, plugins, webserver, lighttpd

I am a pretty naive student of programming and absolutely new to lighttpd. I am trying to understand how a simple "Hello world" plugin is constructed. I found the code from a book. The code is as the following.

```
#includes "base.h"
#includes "log.h"
#includes "plugin.h"
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#includes "config.h"
#endif

typedef struct { PLUGIN_DATA; /* no config */ } plugin_data;

INIT_FUNC(mod_helloworld_init) {
  plugin_data *p;
  UNUSED(srv);
  p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));
  log_trace("Hello, World!");
  return p;
}

FREE_FUNC(mod_helloworld_free) {
  plugin_data *p = p_d;
  UNUSED(srv);
  if (p) free(p);
  return HANDLER_GO_ON;
}

int mod_helloworld_plugin_init(plugin *p) {
  p->version = LIGHTTPD_VERSION_ID;
  p->name = buffer_init_string("helloworld");
  p->init = mod_helloworld_init;
  p->cleanup = mod_helloworld_free;
  p->data = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

In this above mentioned code, I don't understand how the function "log_trace" is working. I see that it's not a predefined function in C++. It seems like it has to be written by the programmer himself. Could you explain how is it working?

Answer (score 0):

`log_trace` function is probably declared or defined in the `log.h` header file. See that header file for more information.

Comment: That header file contains the following



#ifndef _LOG_H_
#define _LOG_H_

#include "server.h"


/* Close fd and _try_ to get a /dev/null for it instead.
 * Returns 0 on success and -1 on failure (fd gets closed in all cases)
 */
int openDevNull(int fd);

#define WP() log_error_write(srv, __FILE__, __LINE__, "");

int open_logfile_or_pipe(server *srv, const char* logfile);

int log_error_open(server *srv);
int log_error_close(server *srv);
int log_error_write(server *srv, const char *filename, unsigned int line, const char *fmt, ...);
int log_error_cycle(server *srv);

#endif

Comment: I cant' see anything about log_trace in it.